# Get a random client with no call history and order by the amount of calls they didn't answer

Tags: mysql, database

I have a simple database with a clients table. I also have a (phone) calls table. So when I call a client, the call will be logged.

Calls have a type id, all related to the topic of the call, except type id 11, which means they didn't pick up the phone.

So what I am trying to do is a get a random client to call, that has no history of picked up calls but then I want to order them by how many times they haven't answered.

I don't want to get a client that Ive called but hasn't picked up when theres clients available that I haven't even attempted to call yet. I want both, but the latter first.

```
SELECT clients.* 
FROM clients 
LEFT JOIN calls ON calls.client = clients.id and calls.type != 11
GROUP BY clients.id 
HAVING COUNT(calls.id) < 1 
ORDER BY RAND() ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is where Im up to so far, It gets a random client without calls (except type 11) and then picks a random one

I just don't know how to order them by the amount of calls they didn't pick up in ASC order

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

get count of calls first and then join on client

below will give you the idea

```
Select * From 
Clients
Left Join
(
SELECT client, count(client) call_count
FROM calls
Where calls.type != 11
GROUP BY call.client
) calls
ON clients.id = calls.client  
ORDER BY RAND() ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is this possible to do without a subquery?